# How to extract exponents from a PDF (Python PDFminer)?

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, pdfminer

I have mathematical exponents followed by words in a PDF (like footnotes, but they are before the word). I would like to extract them without having to use XML. So far I'm using PDFminer, which gives a good rendition of the text but the exponent is rendered as a normal number. It is essential to me to have that exponent, though.

The code I'm using is:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO
import re

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):

        interpreter.process_page(page)

    global text
    text = retstr.getvalue()
    #return text

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
#print(convert_pdf_to_txt('fel_split.pdf'))
```

Either there is a method I don't know of to extract apices too, or I would have to transform them from the pdf to Python through the library into something else, not just a number. I don't know how to proceed.